# Java Hibernate.merge may in any circunstance return null?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hello i have a snippet like this.

```
public void update(Student student)
{
    student=super.merge(student);
    currentSession().update(student);
    return;
}
```

But sometimes this code throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create saveOrUpdate event with null entity.
```

I was wondering how is this possible merge may return null in any circunstance?

Because i have checked `Student` is not null because if is null `merge` would throw.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create merge event with null entity
```

The only situation i think is happening this stuff is if `merge` is returning null is this possible??

Sorry if this question is simple thanks a lot a best regards from Venezuela..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merge() is used to merge a detached object with an attached object (both have the same id). For example, you passed in a student1 object in method update(), which has an id and its status is detached:

```
public void update(Student student1)
{
    //student1 is in detached status, you may modify it if not yet done
    student1.setName("ABC");

    //now load a student2 from db with the same id, note student2 is in persistent status
    Student student2 = currentSession().load(Student.class, student1.getId());

    //merge student1 to student2 and return a new student3
    Student student3 = currentSession().merge(student1);
    //--done, checkout student3, you will see "ABC" is merged. You can't call update() in this case. 
    return;
}
```

If you just want to update passed in student, then remove `student=super.merge(student);`, call saveOrUpdate(), like this:

```
public void update(Student student)
{
    currentSession().saveOrUpdate(student);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Sorry we have found the problem in a completely different place.. sorry... thanks by your answer i will mark it as resolved because your question is very clean.